# MERN stack application PUT 401 Unauthorized even though Bearer token is passed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, mern

I integrated Razorpay payment gateway in my e-commerce website so after the payment is done a success action is dispatched so that the order is updated in the database. The problem comes right after the payment is done so instead of the success payment action it dispatched failure action because it says its 401 unauthorized. I am passing the bearer token and everything but still I dont know why it says unauthorized.

orderController.js

```
const updateOrderToPaid = asyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id)

    console.log(order);
    try {
        if (order) {
            console.log(req.params.id);
            console.log(order);
        
        const updatedOrder = await order.save()
        res.json(updatedOrder)
        }else {
            
            res.status(404)
            throw new Error('Order not found')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
})
```

orderRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { updateOrderToPaid } = require('../controllers/orderController');

const protect = require('../middleware/auth')
router.route('/:id/pay').put(protect,updateOrderToPaid)
```

orderActions.js

```
export const payOrder = (id) => async(dispatch,getState) =>{
    try {
        dispatch({
            type:ORDER_PAY_REQUEST
        })
        const {userLogin:{userInfo}} = getState()
 
        const config = {
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                Authorization:`Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }
        console.log(userInfo.token);
        const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/orders/${id}/pay`,config)
        dispatch({
            type:ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS,
            payload:data
        })
    } catch (e) {
     dispatch({
         type:ORDER_PAY_FAIL,
         payload:e.response && e.response.data.message ? e.response.data.message : e.message
     })
    }
 }
```

OrderScreen.js

```
const options = {
            "key": "rzp_test_wHNtWvry6hDx3M", 
            amount:processParams.amount, 
            currency: processParams.currency,
            "name": "Acme Corp",
            "description": "Test Transaction",
            "image": "https://example.com/your_logo",
            "order_id": processParams.orderId, 
            "handler": function (response){
                alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
                alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
                alert(response.razorpay_signature)

                dispatch(payOrder(orderId))     //Action dispatching here right after the payment is done

                console.log('DISPATCHING ACTION HERE');
            },
            "prefill": {
                "name": order.user.name,
                "email": order.user.email,
                "contact": "9999999999"
            },
            
        };
        const paymentObject = new window.Razorpay(options);
        paymentObject.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your request format.
Below is the correct format of axios put request.

const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/orders/${id}/pay`,{},config)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659915/unauthorise-axios-put-request-without-data
follow this for more

Comment: Bro I still get 401 (Unauthorized) :(

Comment: Try to debug it. 
Hit the request with the postman. Then see if it's still giving the error.
If do not then try to print req object in both cases (i.e. postman, frontend) and match them.

Comment: Check for headers to see if you receiving the token. In req object.